# Error running Maven project: Unsupported protocol: t3

Tags: java, maven, jar, weblogic, pom.xml

I have a Maven project for monitoring of weblogic servers through JMX. In the maven `POM.xml`, I specify the dependency for `wlfullclient.jar` through `scope` tag due to previous errors.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/wlfullclient-11.1.1.4.0.jar</systemPath>
    <version>11.1.1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

It builds successfully, however, when running the `jar` file, I get this error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Unsupported protocol: t3
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(Unknown Source)
```

I looked into the MANIFEST file in the built jar file, and noticed it lists all jars in the classpath, except this `wlfullclient.jar` one (and when I add it and update the manifest, it works).

Why is this happening? And how to fix it so it won't miss this classpath in the generated jar file?

UPDATES: these are all my dependencies in `POM.xml`:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/wlfullclient-11.1.1.4.0.jar</systemPath>
    <version>11.1.1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.24</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.8</version>
  </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
```

And here is the `MANIFEST.MF` in the jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: myname
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_80
Class-Path: libs/slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar libs/logback-classic-1.2.1.jar l
 ibs/logback-core-1.2.1.jar libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
Main-Class: main.WLStatusData
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

Comment: This is how scope `system` works. Artifacts with such scope are not packaged together with all other dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ivan has pointed, this is the expected behavior of using *system* scope. You can learn more [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) about it (*Dependency Scope* section).
To include your library jar into the result file you need to install it into your local maven repository with the command `mvn install:install-file`, more details [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) and use it as a simple dependency (without system scope and system path)

Comment: Then what's the workaround? If I don't define it with scope, I can't even compile the project. It won't 'build success'

Comment: I've updated the answer with the description of what can be done

Comment: In case you have full paths to your other dependencies in your MANIFEST file and they aren't included in the result jar file physically, then I think I need to see the rest of pom.xml for further help.

Comment: Thanks. I did that now, but still not able to run. BTW, what is packaging field? I assume the other fields are what I have in my `POM.xml`? I don't have packaging there.

Comment: Packaging (if you talk about the parameter in `install-file` maven call) is the type of artifact you are going to install, in your case it should be `jar`

Comment: Cool! Now included in the manifest, and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help:)